# Adding arrow to existing menu

Tags: css, css-shapes

Here is my css code where i want to add arrow-down.gif for the menu have child items.

**Css :** MyCSSMenu Core CSS [Do Not Modify!]

```
 .qmmc .qmdivider {
     display:block;
     font-size:1px;
     border-width:0px;
     border-style:solid;
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
 }
 .qmmc .qmdividery {
     float:left;
     width:0px;
 }
 .qmmc .qmtitle {
     display:block;
     cursor:default;
     white-space:nowrap;
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
 }
 .qmclear {
     font-size:1px;
     height:0px;
     width:0px;
     clear:left;
     line-height:0px;
     display:block;
     float:none !important;
 }
 .qmmc {
     position:relative;
     zoom:1;
     z-index:10;
 }
 .qmmc a, .qmmc li {
     float:left;
     display:block;
     white-space:nowrap;
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
 }
 .qmmc div a, .qmmc ul a, .qmmc ul li {
     float:none;
 }
 .qmsh div a {
     float:left;
 }
 .qmmc div {
     visibility:hidden;
     position:absolute;
 }
 .qmmc li {
     z-index:auto;
 }
 .qmmc ul {
     left:-10000px;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:10;
 }
 .qmmc, .qmmc ul {
     list-style:none;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
 }
 .qmmc li a {
     float:none
 }
 .qmmc li:hover>ul {
     left:auto;
 }
 #qm0 ul {
     top:100%;
 }
 #qm0 ul li:hover>ul {
     top:0px;
     left:100%;
 }
 #qm0 a {
     padding:5px 4px 5px 5px;
     color:#7a7a7a;
     /*font-family:Arial;*/
     font-size:14px;
     font-weight:bold;
     text-decoration:none;
     background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-x;
     height:30px;
     line-height:33px;
 }
 #qm0 div, #qm0 ul {
     padding:2px;
     margin:-2px 0px 0px;
     background-color:#f7f7f7;
     border-width:1px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:#7a7a7a;
 }
 #qm0 div a, #qm0 ul a {
     padding:3px 10px 3px 5px;
     background-color:#7a7a7a;
     font-size:14px;
     border-width:0px;
     border-style:none;
     height:20px;
     line-height:23px;
     background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-y;
     color:#7a7a7a;
 }
 #qm0 div a:hover, #qm0 ul a:hover {
     background-color:#cdcdcd;
     color:#7a7a7a;
 }
 body #qm0 div .qmactive, body #qm0 div .qmactive:hover {
     background-color:#7a7a7a;
     color:#cc0000;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
 #qm0 .qmtitle {
     cursor:default;
     padding:3px 0px 3px 4px;
     color:#7a7a7a;
     /*font-family:arial;*/
     font-size:14px;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
 #qm0 .qmdividerx {
     border-top-width:1px;
     margin:4px 0px;
     border-color:#bfbfbf;
 }
 #qm0 .qmdividery {
     border-left-width:1px;
     height:15px;
     margin:4px 2px 0px;
     border-color:#555;
 }
 #qm0 .qmritem span {
     border-color:#dadada;
     background-color:#f7f7f7;
 }
 #qm0 .qmritemcontent {
     padding:0px 0px 0px 4px;
 }
```

**html :**

```
  <ul id="qm0" class="qmmc">
<li><a href="/" title="Home Page">Home</a>
</li>// no arrow here
<li><a class="qmparent" href="#" title="News">News</a> //here the arrow should appear
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/news.php?cid=1" title="Coastal News">Coastal News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/news.php?cid=2" title="State News">State News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/news.php?cid=3" title="National News">National News</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="qmparent" href="#" title="Features">Features</a> //here the arrow should appear
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/news.php?cid=7" title="Editorial">Editorial</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/news.php?cid=8" title="Special Report">Special Report</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The code is taken from **mycssmenu**

Comment: Can you please fix your CSS to make it legible...?

Comment: Add a class to the <li> elements that have a submenu (<ul>) and call it "submenu". Than in your css .submenu{background:url(path_to_img/arrow-down.gif) 0 0 no-repeat} This will put the arrow on the <li> elements that have a "sumbenu" class, in the top left corner of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To show the arrows not only on hover, remove the `:hover`-pseudo class. I updated the fiddles, too.

### **Pure CSS way**

You can solve this with CSS only using the border property like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f9k8at1/)):

```
.qmmc > li {
  margin-right: 12px;
}


.qmmc > li.has-sub:after {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 50%;
 right: -12px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
 border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent; 
}
```

### **Using Background image**

You can add the image like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haox19uv/))

```
 .qmmc > li {
   margin-right: 12px;
 }

.qmmc > li.has-sub:after {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   content: '';
   width: 12px;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0%;
   right: -12px;
   background: url(PATH/TO/IMAGE/arrow-down.gif) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: contain;
 }
```

Using CSS only would be the cleaner, more modern approach.

Comment: neither work for me. i m using G.chrome. The arrow should appear for only if there is sub menus. and before hover. thanks

Comment: hi, it looks good.  1) is it possible to set different color when mouse over menu (Home, News, feature...)
2)also is it possible to show up-arrow when the menu drops down ^ sign

Comment: @DilDilshan, both of this is possible, look for :hover-pseudo class:
`.qmmc > li ul li:hover { background: #ccc /*insert bg color code*/ }` this changes the bg-color of the hovered element.

`.qmmc > li.has-sub:hover:after { border-style:solid; border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px; border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent }`
this enables the arrow up.

Comment: hi, i updated your fiddles but nothing is appearing
http://jsfiddle.net/haox19uv/1/

Comment: hi, i think i have problem using that css code and i m forced to change the css. now the menu content this code where i need to add drop downs
[code]
#header .nav { float:left;}
#header .nav li { float:left;}
#header .nav li a { float:left; font-size:15px; color:#7a7a7a; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; height:35px; line-height:33px; padding:10px 15px;}
    #header .nav li a:hover { background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; color:#8ac404;}
    #header .nav li a.current { background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; color:#8ac404;}
[/code]

Answer (score 1):

An elegant CSS only solution will be to use pseudo elements.

Adding this to your CSS will do exactly what you want:

```
.qmmc li > a:after { 
margin-left: 4px; 
content: url(link/to/right-arrow.png); 
}                              /* This will be used when you have sub-sub-menus*/

.qmmc > li > a:after {
margin-left: 4px;
content: url(link/to/down-arrow.png); 
}                              /* This will be used when you have sub-menus*/

.qmmc li > a:only-child:after { 
margin-left: 0; 
content: ''; 
}                              /* This will be used when you have no sub-menus*/
```

You can change the `content` to `'\25BA'` and `'\25BC'` in 1st and 2nd definitions respectively to get nice arrows without using images.  See a [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/eua0z7g3/), see that I have added a further sub-menu to "Costal News" sub-menu item for demonstration.

Comment: hi, it works but the previous background colors and menus colors dont appear.

Comment: @DilDilshan i tried your code without my solution but couldnt figure out which background color you are referring to.. Can you edit my fiddle or create a new fiddle to demonstrate exactly that.. I will try to update my solution to suit..

Comment: hi, thanks it works :) 
 1) is it possible to set different color when mouse over menu (Home, News, feature...) 2)also is it possible to show up-arrow when the menu drops down ^ sign

Comment: You can add something like `ul li:hover { background-color:#dedede; }` to your CSS for background color change on hover. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, i updated you fiddles, the bg color changes but not the font color 
ul li:hover { background-color:#f3f3f3; color:#000000;}

Comment: something like `ul li > a:hover {color: #000!important;}` will be able to override other CSS that may be defined previously(see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eua0z7g3/13/)).  I would suggest cleaning your final CSS to remove any redundancy will be required.

Comment: hi, i think i have problem using that css code and i m forced to change the css. now the menu content this code where i need to add drop downs [code] #header .nav { float:left;} #header .nav li { float:left;} #header .nav li a { float:left; font-size:15px; color:#7a7a7a; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; height:35px; line-height:33px; padding:10px 15px;} #header .nav li a:hover { background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; color:#8ac404;} #header .nav li a.current { background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; color:#8ac404;} [/code] –

Comment: You will find a grey check mark just below the up/down vote arrow to the left of my answer.  When you click on that check mark, it will change color and mark my answer as accepted.  Thanks and Cheers!!